# Android strange bug while downloading a JSON

Tags: java, android, json, download

I need to download a JSON in a string, i'm almost sure the code isn't wrong, but there's something strange...

```
public boolean downloadJSON(){
    json="";
    try{
        URL url = new URL(theURL);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json+=line;
        }
        in.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically it open the buffer correctly, it read the json correctly and store it in the variable, it close the stream, then it go to the return true and... It randomly jump to the return false without sense, and while it's on the return false the Exception e is... null O.o
That make absolutely no sense, help me please D:!!!

In the end i solved it in this way:

```
public boolean downloadJSON(){
    json="";
    boolean out=false;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(theURL);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json+=line;
        }
        in.close();
        out = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  return out;
}
```

Don't ask me how this is supposed to be correct if the first doesen't work, in my mind i still think the first should work :S

ADD: for Stephen C:

```
public boolean downloadJSON(){
        json="";
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://fapfapfap.altervista.org/conapo/conapo.php?n="+numeroPagina);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){json+=line;}
            in.close();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERRORE", e.getStackTrace().toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is null O.o ? Is it NullPointerException ?

Comment: impossible. If you return false, `e` is absolutely NOT null. Add this before your return in the catch block. `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Can you provide the URL? If it's a offline URL, is it just returning a JSON?

Comment: The url is: http://fapfapfap.altervista.org/conapo/conapo.php?n=1 and it's correctly read by the code and saved in the json String

Comment: well, i solved, but thanks anyway :D

Comment: @FedericoCapece, I'm glad you find the solution! Do you mind sharing it? I tested your code against the link you provided and it looks like its working seamlessly. 
Also, one suggestion to your code is use StringBuilder over '+' operator for string concatenation as '+' operator creates intermediate strings in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL(theURL);
StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }

System.out.println(jsonResults.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, this work, anyway it still make no sense that my code jumped to the false without exception :S

Comment: you are using string to append data, instead of which you should use stringbuilder like this..                                                                                                                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      in), 1024);
    String line;
    while ((line = bfrd.readLine()) != null)
     stringbuilder.append(line);

    downloadedString = stringbuilder.toString();

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> .... it still make no sense that my code jumped to the false without exception

You are misinterpreting the evidence:

```
public boolean downloadJSON(){
    json = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(theURL);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json += line;
        }
        in.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;  // HERE
    }
}
```

When you get to the statement I've labelled `// HERE`. It has happened >>because<< some exception has been thrown.  There is absolutely no doubt about it.  We don't know what exception it was, because your code simply throws away the exception object.

(Try adding `e.printStacktace();` before the `return false;`)

I suspect it is either going to be a `MalformedURLException`, on a `FileNotFoundException` ... but it could be other things.

---

So what are your mistakes in this code?

1)  Catching `Exception` is bad idea.  The problem is that it catches too much.  In addition to catching the exceptions that you (might have) expected at this point, it will catch all of the *unexpected* ones as well.  For example, any NPEs or AIOOPEs or whatever arising from (hypothetical) bugs in your code.

In this case, you should probably catch the exceptions that are likely at this point; i.e. `IOException`.

2)  Catching an exception and throwing away the stacktrace makes it hard to diagnose a problem.  It is only advisable to "squash" an exception like that if you know (and can prove) that the exception is going to be what you expect.

3)  Doing both 1) and 2) in the same piece of code is a REALLY bad idea.

4)  Building a string like that is inefficient (or very inefficient ... if you are loading a really large document).  Using a `StringBuilder` is much better.

Note however the 4) is peripheral to the problem you were having.

Comment: I debugged the code step-by-step, and the json reading was a success, it all worked, and it even went on return true, but while i pressed F8 on return true it jumped on return false, like if return true was the problem...
And the nosense thing was that when it was on the return false the exception was null, like it never entered in the catch :S
anyway now i fixed it by doing what i wrote now in my answer as edit

Comment: I know it makes absolutely no-sense what i'm saying, if i was to answer to this answer i too would probably said that there was some kind of exception, but there isn't D:

Comment: @FedericoCapece - Your "solution" is just as bad as the original version.  You are still catching and squashing `Exception`.  Bad.

Comment: Either you are >>deluding yourself<<, or there is a bug in your IDE's debugger.  Trust me.  I've been programming in Java for > 15 years, and I've seen this kind of stuff before.  I will only believe you if you add a `e.printStackTrace()` and that throws an NPE.

Comment: i put it right now, i added my current code now and... in the logcat there's nothing, and the code still jump from return true to return false, I understand that you can't trust me, it make no sense, if you want i can make a video of the debugging